# python selenium find elements by class return whole website instead of element

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to read the table from this website into a pandas dataframe. [Link here](https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty.htm)

However, when i try to print the `Dataframe` out, it gives me everything on the website such as the top section like `website search`, `advance search`, as well as the bottom section `Disclaimer | Hyperlink Policy | Privacy Policy` and `©2010 Hong Kong Exchanges and Clearing Limited...`

Instead of just the table. Not sure what is the issue here.

```
url = r'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty.htm'


path_to_chrome_driver = r'C:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome_driver)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('table_grey_border').find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
z = pandas.read_html(driver.page_source, flavor='bs4')

print(z)
```

Note: I have also tried the below code, but still same results.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('table_grey_border')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't use the return value from the `find_element_by_class_name` you won't see those results, you need to use the return value of your `find_element_by_class_name`.

Actually you used `driver.page_source` which is the whole html.

Change this :

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('table_grey_border').find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
z = pandas.read_html(driver.page_source, flavor='bs4')
```

To this :

```
res = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table_grey_border').find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
print (res)
```

Comment: @omri_sasdon I get a `TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'WebElement'` error message though. `Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x0000020A06F27668>>
`

Comment: @jakewong, That's because it's not html, try printing res to see the returned value.

Comment: i used `res.get_attribute('outerHTML')` but still cant feed it into pandas to retrieve the table.

Comment: @jakewong res.get_attribute('innerHTML')

Comment: This still doesn't solve my issue. Pandas is still saying that no tables are found.

Comment: @jakewong Are you sure that the selector is returning the table? As i see your'e finding the tbody tag which is an inner tag to the table, consider searching for a tag that wrap the table tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `HTML` code for just a specific element, you need to use below code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('table_grey_border').find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Comment: I'm still not able to read each of the rows into `pandas Dataframe`. It now tells me that no tables have been found

Comment: do you use `z = pandas.read_html(driver.find_element_by_class_name('table_grey_border').find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').get_attribute('outerHTML'), flavor='bs4')` ?

Comment: Yes. I did exactly that. I even rechecked it with your code. still gives me `no tables found`

Comment: could you print the output of my code to check what exactly it returns? also try `get_attribute('innerHTML')` instead of `get_attribute('outerHTML')`